# XIB tableview ignore the size of the tableview goes to full screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a XIB with a nav bar at the top and the tableview directly under that.  both of these are placed under a UIView.

If I change the color of the table in the IB and run that app, the color changes properly. So I assume that I have the XIB loaded OK.

But the tableview take up the entire screen and the nav bar is hidden.

Is there a trick to this?  Do I have to manually set the size (top) in the code, and if so how exactly do I do this?

Comment: I think more detail is needed, in particular what does your view controller look like, is it a UITableViewController, which view is set as it's `view` property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create set the file as a subclass of  `UITableViewController` and you can either set the `UINavigationBar` as an outlet or allocate it in the `viewdidLoad` method -

Watch this tutorial to understand on how to set things up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw